explanation of conditional probability on the sum of two random variables
I'm reading through a "brief review of probability theory" section in a text book (and in particular a paragraph on conditional probability) and the author makes this statement:
If $z = x + y$  and the conditional pdf of $y$ given $x$  is $p_{y|x}(\cdot)$ then
$$p(z|x) = p_{y|x}(z-x)$$
And I'm not seeing how this connection is made. At this point the author hasn't said anything about $x$ and $y$ other than they're random variables. I get that in conditional probability in general is $ P\{A|B\} = \frac{P\{A,B\}}{P\{B\}}$ and so you can do $p(y|x) = \frac{p(y,x)}{p(x)} = \frac{p(z-x,x)}{p(x)}$ but don't see how to manipulate that to the above statement.
Apologies if this is a simple question.

By definition of the pdf, for any $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$
$$
\mathbb P(Z\in A\mid X=x)=\int_A p_{Z|X}(z|x) dz
$$
and at the same time
$$
\mathbb P(Z\in A\mid X=x)=\mathbb P(X+Y\in A\mid X=x)=\mathbb P(Y\in A-x\mid X)=\int_{A-x} p_{Y|X}(y|x) dy=\{y=z-x\}=\int_{A} p_{Y|X}(z-x|x) dz
$$
yielding $ p_{Z|X}(z|x)=p_{Y|X}(z-x|x)$ by a.s. uniqueness of the density.
